# Insufficient privileges while changing password

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to use Azure Powershell (AZ powershell module) inside docker container to create/modify office 365 related configurations including user profiles.

I am trying to change user password using service principal. I have got the following error while using `Update-AzADUser`. However, I could create the user and modify the display name. I was having issues only with the change password or removing the user.

> PS /> `Update-AzADUser -ObjectId xyz358c2... -Password $password`
>   Update-AzADUser : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + `Update-AzADUser -ObjectId xyz358c2... -Passw ...`
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-AzADUser], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.UpdateAzureADUserCommand

On the service principal, I have provided all available application permission and delegated permissions on *Microsoft Graph API* and *Windows Azure Active Directory*.

I can't find any of the AD roles that are available in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles to assign to the service principal. Please screenshots on the below links.

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTGqn.png)

[Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NFS4.png)

Comment: Yeah.. Those are highly privileged operations. To allow those for the principal, you might need to assign a directory role to the service principal using PowerShell. You can see the list of available roles here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles.

Comment: Thanks a lot of the reply! I have went through the similar comment in another stack over flow thread. I have got mac machine. How can I add directory role using Powershell Core or Azure Powershell?

Comment: I think suggestion from @juunas is a good one (as usual I may add).. To answer your question about how to add directory role for service principal using PowerShell.. you can use a combination of `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember` and `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` .. In terms of directory role something like `Helpdesk admninstrator` should do at least for resetting passwords for non-admin users.. you can choose a more privileged directory role than that if need be based on your requirements..

Comment: @Shreedhar Also know that there can be scenarios where RoleTemplate isn't already enabled.. so it will be a bit of scripting.. I'll try to see if I can test something quick and add an answer..

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit and Juunas. AzureAD is windows specific. I was wondering whether how you do it on Mac. 

Anyway, I am trying to run those commands by finding windows machine. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you should try to assign an appropriate directory role to the service principal you are using, so that it can get sufficient privileges.

Here is a quick script to do that. Change the service principal name and roleName as per your requirements.

```
# Get to the service principal
$svcPrincipalId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "your service principal name").ObjectId

# I am using Helpdesk administrator here, but feel free to change this name as per your requirement. 
# You can get a complete list of role templates using Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate. 
# Helpdesk admninstrator role can reset passwords for non-administrators.
$roleName = 'Helpdesk administrator'

# Fetch User Account Administrator role instance
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq $roleName}

# If role instance does not exist, instantiate it based on the role template
if ($role -eq $null) {

    # Instantiate an instance of the role template
    $roleTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq $roleName}
    Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $roleTemplate.ObjectId

    # Fetch User Account Administrator role instance again
    $role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq $roleName}
}


# Add user to role
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId $svcPrincipalId
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit for detailed information. I will give a shot and update you. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit for the script. I used Company Administrator role for testing. It worked like Charm!

Comment: Just remember that the service principal is now global admin.. Be careful with the keys.

Comment: Sure Junas! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Also Company Administrator is a highly privileged role as @juunas correctly highlighted above. I had used Helpdesk Administrator in my sample script, which should be good for most common scenarios.